# Unable to set value for a person type column using workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, person

In my sharepoint application when a list is saved it will call a workflow.

In the workflow, I am trying to set assigned to a field (person type) with value in Approver name (this is the string value which is the display name of the name field which is person type).

But this value is not getting set. There is no error, but the value in `assigned to` field is null

Comment: Is Name(person field) exists in same list?

Comment: yes. its in same list

Comment: So why don't you use the Name field to set the assigned to field?

Comment: tried that also, but didnt work. this is done in  workflow. for some users  its working, for some its not :(